# Hive Query with collect_set

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have 2 tables,  `sample_table1` with two columns as below

```
C1  C2
001  a
001  b
001  e
002  c
002  b
003  a
003  c
```

and `sample_table2` with two columns as

```
C3  C4
a   0
b   1
c   0
d   1
e   0
```

I want to get an output like

```
F1    F2
001    1    <as 001 -> [a, b, e] -> [0, 1, 0] -> 1 (if one of the items in the collection ([a, b, e] in this case) is 1, then Column F2 should be 1 )>
002    1    <as 002 -> [c, b] -> [0, 1] -> 1>
003    0    <as 003 -> [a, c] -> [0, 0] -> 0>
```

I tried a lot with Hive's built in aggregate function `collect_set`, but could not solve it. I am wondering if I can do it without writing any custom UDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `collect_set`

```
select      t1.c1       as f1
           ,max(t2.c4)  as f2

from                sample_table1 t1
            join    sample_table2 t2
            on      t1.c2 = t2.c3

group by    t1.c1      
;
```

---

```
+-----+----+
| f1  | f2 |
+-----+----+
| 001 |  1 |
| 002 |  1 |
| 003 |  0 |
+-----+----+
```